# Javascript - angular passing a variable from a controller to a function in a service not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to javascript and angular so this question is quit a newbee question. I am trying to pass a variable from my controller to a service and then use it in my function, but when I do the console.log I don't get the variable. This is my controller:

```
var message = "Some error message.";
ErrorService.alertMessage(message);
```

And my factory:

```
.factory('ErrorService', function() {
  return {
    alertMessage: function(message) {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

console.log(message);

      function onDeviceReady(message) {

        console.log(message);

        if (navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {
          navigator.notification.alert(
            message,   // the message
            function() {},                      // a callback
            "Error",                            // a title
            "OK"                                // the button text
          );
        } else {
          alert(message);
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

The first `console.log` gives me the variable value, but the second `console.log` inside `onDeviceReady` function doesn't output anything.

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Are you sure it supports the `deviceready` event? If it does, why are you trying to use `deviceready` for this? Your code is probably running _after_ any `deviceready` event would have fired.

Comment: I am runnig it on Ionic, and everything worked fine when I had onDeviceReady function inside each controller where I was outputing error messages, it just stoped working when I moved it to the services